# Why is the dephasing time T2* gaussian?

Tags: decoherence

In MRI dephasing is characterized by $T_2^*$.

$T_2^*$ is measured by performing a Ramsey experiment and is defined as the 1/e decay time of the measured oscillation.

I have read, in

> Universal dynamical decoupling of a single solid-state spin from a spin bath. G. de Lange et al. [*Science* **330**, p.60 (2010)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1192739), [arXiv:1008.2119](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2119)

that when there is a slow spin bath the decay will be a Gaussian but cannot find any good sources describing why.

Could someone explain me why the decay has a gaussian ($e^{-(t/\tau)^2} $)profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found some articles that might be of interest to you:

[An analytical semiclassical treatment](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary;jsessionid=50F6B65F0DA688309747EBF6CACE48CD?doi=10.1.1.243.1135) ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.65.205309))

[A simulation of the spin decoherence due to a randomly fluctuating spin bath](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2541) ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/PhysRevB.88.085323))

[A comprehensive review](http://www.physics.hku.hk/~wangyao/papers/NJP2007.pdf) ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/9/7/226))

What I've managed to understand, from briefly reading these papers, is that the gaussian decoherence is a result of the broadening of the energy of the spins from inhomogeneity in the magnetic field (due to thermal fluctuations of the spin bath).
This broadening causes the spins to go out of sync such that their sum decays as a gaussian.

You may also find [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.7506) ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.88.085320)) helpful.